# can't boot into ubuntu please help my files are all gone

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a Windows 8 based Sony Vaio laptop.

Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop alongside windows, now I can't login into Ubuntu anymore. The boot menu directly boots into Windows 8 and doesn't show the grub menu.

All my files are on Ubuntu, how can I access it or at least how can I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

try pressing shift right after the bios and see if you can get a boot menu. If you really need your files back but know you can't boot into ubuntu, boot the livecd and copy the files from the filesystem to a usb